# How do I compile sass code into a css file in another directory?

Tags: css, sass

I want to incorporate the SMACSS architecture into a site that I am building.

On my desktop I have a folder named after the site which I am building. Containing my **css**,**js** **images** and **sass** folders.

All the contents of the sass folders are partials which I import into a main.scss file(contained within the **sass** directory).

Here is my **sass** directory:

```
sass/
|
base
| _ file.scss
| _ file1.scss
|
layout
| _ file.scss
| _ file1.scss
|
module
| _ file.scss
| _ file1.scss
|
state
| _ file.scss
| _ file1.scss
|
theme
| _ file.scss
| _ file1.scss
```

I want to compile my main.scss file into a file called **stylesheet.css** which should be inside the **css** folder.

I have tried:

```
sass --watch main.scss:stylesheet.css
```

With no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing `sass` relatively to current directory, so keep it in mind, and enter path to your files according to it:

```
sass --watch main.scss:../css/stylesheet.css
```

Or call `sass` from the root of your project:

```
sass --watch sass/main.scss:css/stylesheet.css
```